# How to decline an adjective, referring to different nouns?

Tags: грамматика

How to make a sentence with an adjective which refers to different nouns? Do I have to put it twice?

For instance

> Его приветствовали с большим ликованием и радостью.
> Его приветствовали с большим ликованием и большой радостью.
> Его приветствовали с большим ликованием и с большой радостью.
>
> Она принесла охлаждённые сосиски и молоко.
> Она принесла охлаждённые сосиски и охлаждённое молоко.
>
> Нам нужно масло и вода.
> Нам нужно масло и нужна так же вода.

And how is it, if the verb refers to words with different numeral? Would it be like

> Ей нравится лилия и вот эти растения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grammatical norms require that adjective was put in plural form.

> Его приветствовали с большими ликованием и радостью.

if adj. is in singular form, it is dependent on closest noun in same grammatical case.

however, it is impossible to say from

> Она принесла охлаждённые сосиски и молоко.

if the milk was cooled, as the adjective must be in plural form either way. To disambiguate, one of the following must be used:

> Она принесла молоко и охлаждённые сосиски. (sausage is cool, but not milk)
>
> Она принесла охлаждённые молоко и сосиски. (both sausage and milk are cool)
>
> Она принесла охлаждённое молоко и сосиски. (only milk is cool)

In colloquial speech, however, many clumsy constructs are used because people don't build the sentence before starting to speak it. In 'Hi-Russian' (written language and language of public speeches) this should be avoided. Examples:

The adjective may be declined together with the closest noun. While **grammatically incorrect**, the following sentence may occur in common speech and states, that both oil and water are needed. The reason is, that at the moment when the speaker tells 'нужно' he automatically decline it with 'масло', but later says that water is also needed, but 'нужно' is already said. This is a grammatical error, but extremely common even among native speakers.

> Нам нужно масло и вода.

or adjective may be repeated

> Она принесла охлаждённые сосиски и охлаждённое молоко.

Comment: likely a typo: ``Она принесла охлаждённОе молокО и сосиски.``

Comment: It should be `Нам нужнЫ масло и вода.` "Mасло и вода" is the subject of this sentence, and the predicate **must** agree in number with the subject. `X and Y` is always "they" when it's the subject, both in Russian and in English, so the predicate **must** be plural in this sentence.

Comment: If you _write_ down colloquial speech, you still have to use the punctuation that corresponds to it's structure as it was uttered. If it's _but **later** says that water is also needed_, so the sentence should look like this: `Нам нужно масло. И вода.` Only in such case it makes sense, otherwise it sounds like "три медведь".

Comment: @YellowSky I'm not telling what right and wrong, I merely describe what occurs in the wild. And yes, I explicitly stated that this such sentence is grammatically incorrect. Please, don't fume about it.

Comment: You know, everyone can speak in a wrong way, but our task is to show how to speak _correctly_. It's best not to write down ungrammatical sentences at all, and if you do write them down, they've got to be explicitly marked as ungrammatical, for example with an asterisk. The only reason to write them down is to tell that one _should not_ speak that way, and the correct variant must always be presented.

Comment: Wait, if I want to be clear about that the sausages *and* the milk is cooled, I'd have to write *Она принесла охлаждённЫЕ молоко и сосиски.* (plural adjective and noun in singular first), right?

Comment: @embert exactly. I updated the post.

Comment: @YellowSky, permeakra I believe there's nothing to argue about, especially in a such expressive manner. Please, calm down.

Comment: @YellowSky Нам нужно масло и вода is a form that is de-facto used quite often in colloquial speech, I see no reasons to argue about it.

Comment: @shabunc - The vowel sounds in нужно are usually reduced so much that one can hardly tell whether a person says нужно or нужны, even despite the difference in stress, but it doesn't mean that one should write it in a wrong way.

Comment: @YellowSky There is a stress shift between these two forms, so they are easily distinguishable. And yeah, sir Grammar Fuhrer.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, most of your sentences can be used in spoken speech, with the exception of

```
Нам нужно масло и нужна так же вода
```

That's invalid, although you could say

```
Нам нужно масло и нужна вода, or
Нам нужно масло и так же нужна вода
```

From the rest of your sentences, you would usually only say the first versions in spoken speech.

Also,

```
"Ей нравится лилия и вот эти растения"
```

would need to become plural by changing to

```
"Ей нравЯтся лилиИ и вот эти растения"
```

I know you asked specifically for what to do with different numbers in the same clause, but you really can't say something like that, just how in English you wouldn't say "She likes a lily and these plants".

If, on the other hand, you wanted to say something like "She likes this [specific] lily and these plants, you could say

```
"Ей нравятся эта лилия и эти растения"
```